# Can't change table of Laravel's Auth

Tags: php, database, laravel, authentication, model

I've got a weird problem with my laravel. I'm using the auth of laravel but I have a different DB. So I've changed the name of the table using `protected $table = 'compte';`, but once I tryed something that required my table like login, it doesn't returned me an error except if I tryed to register a new user. With register, it gave me that it still use `dbname.users` instead of `dbname.compte`. 
Here is what I changed in the User model :

```
protected $table = 'compte';
protected $primaryKey = 'id_compte';
public $timestamps = false;


// SET A DIFFERENT FIELD FOR THE PASSWORD DUE TO THE DB
public function getAuthPassword() { 
    return $this->mdp_compte; 
}
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the config/auth.php file? If no, there is the problem.

Comment: what changes do I need to do ? I don't what to change in auth.php.

Answer (score 2):

Change the table name to `compte` in your `config/auth.php`.
Also clear all caches by the command
`php artisan cache:clear`.

Here is a default code

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
```

You need to change it

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Compte::class,
        ],
```

Comment: sorry for my question but what I nedd to change in auth.php ?

Comment: you should change providers array.

Comment: I haven't change my original files after using php artisan make:auth. So do I need to chnage the name of the file User.php to Compte.php ? I've tryed your method but it didn't work. It still use `users`